How can I search a Google Sheet for the cell that matches the intersection of the first column and top row of another sheet
I have made a mockup of my google sheet here. (My actual data consists of 105 rows, if that matters.)
I'm stumped once again. I know I've done this before, and I know I found the answer on here, but I cannot recall how I did or correctly formulate my search to turn up the how-to again.
I have a data sheet with:



Parent/Guardian
Student (age)
Class
Class Period




Joni Smith
Sally Smith (11)
Debate with Mr. Tom Jones
1st Period


Joni Smith
Sally Smith (11)
U.S. History with Ms. Jan Green
2nd Period


Joni Smith
Dan Smith (13)
Computer Animation with Mr. Mike Martin
2nd Period


Joni Smith
Dan Smith (13)
Bicycle Repair with Ms. Jane Good
1st Period


Ben Jones
Jill Jones (11)
Acrylic Painting with Mr. Bill Bobbins
3rd Period


Ben Jones
Jill Jones (11)
World History with Mr. Robert Robbins
1st Period


Mary Brown
Nancy Brown (11)
Drawing: Pen and Ink with Ms. Nancy McDuff
2nd Period


Mary Brown
Nancy Brown (11)
Acrylic Painting with Mr. Bill Bobbins
3rd Period


Mary Brown
Nancy Brown (11)
Bicycle Repair with Ms. Jane Good
1st Period


Mary Brown
Nancy Brown (11)
Gym with Coach Ronald Doubtfire
4th Period


Mary Brown
Joe Brown (12)
Drawing: Pen and Ink with Ms. Nancy McDuff
2nd Period


Mary Brown
Joe Brown (12)
Debate with Mr. Tom Jones
1st Period


Mary Brown
Joe Brown (12)
Gym with Coach Ronald Doubtfire
4th Period


Mary Brown
Joe Brown (12)
Theater: Shakespeare with Ms. Billie Boxer
3rd Period


Mary Brown
Jack Brown (14)
Algebra I with Ms. Kathy Cook
3rd Period


John Black
Ann Black (13)
Swimming with Coach Sally Green
1st Period


John Black
Ann Black (13)
Theater: Shakespeare with Ms. Billie Boxer
3rd Period


John Black
Sam Black (15)
Swimming with Coach Sally Green
1st Period


John Black
Sam Black (15)
U.S. History with Ms. Jan Green
2nd Period


John Black
Sam Black (15)
Theater: Shakespeare with Ms. Billie Boxer
3rd Period



I want to make another sheet that is:



Student (age)
Parent/Guardian
1st Period
2nd Period
3rd Period
4th Period




Sally Smith (11)
Joni Smith
Debate with Mr. Tom Jones
U.S. History with Ms. Jan Green




Dan Smith (13)
Joni Smith
Bicycle Repair with Ms. Jane Good
Computer Animation with Mr. Mike Martin




Jill Jones (11)
Ben Jones
World History with Mr. Robert Robbins

Acrylic Painting with Mr. Bill Bobbins



Nancy Brown (11)
Mary Brown
Bicycle Repair with Ms. Jane Good.
Drawing: Pen and Ink with Ms. Nancy McDuff
Acrylic Painting with Mr. Bill Bobbins
Gym with Coach Ronald Doubtfire


Joe Brown (12)
Mary Brown
Debate with Mr. Tom Jones
Drawing: Pen and Ink with Ms. Nancy McDuff
Theater: Shakespeare with Ms. Billie Boxer
Gym with Coach Ronald Doubtfire


Jack Brown (14)
Mary Brown


Algebra I with Ms. Kathy Cook



Ann Black (13)
John Black
Swimming with Coach Sally Green

Theater: Shakespeare with Ms. Billie Boxer



Sam Black (15)
John Black
Swimming with Coach Sally Green
U.S. History with Ms. Jan Green
Theater: Shakespeare with Ms. Billie Boxer




I used UNIQUE to extract all the student names the first column of the results sheet. And TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE) to extract the class periods for the top row. Now I need to search the data sheet for the class title that matches both the student name and the class period.
I have made a mockup of my google sheet here.


You may try:
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,map(B1:F1,lambda(Λ,if(left(Λ)="P",xlookup(Σ,'Data Sheet'!B:B,'Data Sheet'!A:A,),ifna(filter('Data Sheet'!C:C,'Data Sheet'!B:B=Σ,'Data Sheet'!D:D=Λ))))))))



Perfect, except that it revealed that someone is signed up for TWO second-period classes (the registration system should not have allowed that, but that's a separate problem to address). I don't know if I need to solve that here (what I need to do is get the student's schedule straightened out), but is there a way to flag the period with two classes as a problem while filling in the data for the remaining columns?

You could look into conditional formatting (one example here which you can adapt accordingly) to highlight such rows which has more than one(unique) instance of student+class+period
